# Non-copying std::shared_ptr<boost::any>?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14, shared-ptr

I store "instances of different types" with "shared ownership". That's what I currently do:

```
class Destructible {
public:
    virtual ~Destructible() = default;
};

// UGLY
class MyType1 : public Destructible { ... };
class MyTypeN : public Destructible { ... };

class Storage {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Destructible>> objects_;
    ...
}
```

I'd love to switch to `boost::any`, removing all these conformances and gaining the ability to store instances of truly any type. Also I like `boost::any` interface and `boost::any_cast`.

But my types don't satisfy `ValueType` requirements, they are not copyable. What is the best (preferably existing) solution for this problem? Something like `shared_any_ptr`, which captures destructor at creation, has type erasure, reference counter and can do `any_cast`.

Edit: `boost::any` allows creation with move, but I'd prefer not to even move and use pointers.
Edit2: I also use `make_shared` extensively, so something `make_shared_any_ptr` would come in handy.

Comment: Write your own `any`? It's the simplest of all the type erasures, so it's a good exercise.

Comment: @Barry Just wondering whether there is any existing solution to the problem in Boost or somewhere.

Comment: You could use `boost::variant`, it is also much type-safer.

Comment: @IgorR. In my case I need type erasure in `Storage`. I even want to remove the base class limitation to store `TheirType`s as well ;)

Comment: Can you explain why the combinatin of shared_ptr and any does not solve your problem?

Comment: @Beginner `any` type erasing copying, and some of his types cannot be copied.

Comment: @Yakk shared pointer does not copy the referenced element, so that should do the trick, right?

Comment: @Beginner No it shouldn't.  Type erased operations don't care if they are used or not: how to do them is saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't tricky with shared pointers.  We can even avoid multiple allocations.

```
struct any_block {
  any_block(any_block const&)=delete;
  template<class T>
  T* try_get() {
    if (!info || !ptr) return nullptr;
    if (std::type_index(typeid(T)) != std::type_index(*info)) return nullptr;
    return static_cast<T*>(ptr);
  }
  template<class T>
  T const* try_get() const {
    if (!info || !ptr) return nullptr;
    if (std::type_index(typeid(T)) != std::type_index(*info)) return nullptr;
    return static_cast<T const*>(ptr);
  }
  ~any_block() {
    cleanup();
  }
protected:
  void cleanup(){
    if (dtor) dtor(this);
    dtor=0;
  }
  any_block() {}
  std::type_info const* info = nullptr;
  void* ptr = nullptr;
  void(*dtor)(any_block*) = nullptr;
};
template<class T>
struct any_block_made:any_block {
  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> data;
  any_block_made() {}
  ~any_block_made() {}
  T* get_unsafe() {
    return static_cast<T*>((void*)&data);
  }
  template<class...Args>
  void emplace(Args&&...args) {
    ptr = ::new((void*)get_unsafe()) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    info = &typeid(T);
    dtor = [](any_block* self){
      static_cast<any_block_made<T>*>(self)->get_unsafe()->~T();
    };
  }
};
template<class D>
struct any_block_dtor:any_block {
  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(D), alignof(D)> dtor_data;
  any_block_dtor() {}
  ~any_block_dtor() {
    cleanup();
    if (info) dtor_unsafe()->~D();
  }
  D* dtor_unsafe() {
    return static_cast<D*>((void*)&dtor_data);
  }
  template<class T, class D0>
  void init(T* t, D0&& d) {
    ::new( (void*)dtor_unsafe() ) D(std::forward<D0>(d));
    info = &typeid(T);
    ptr = t;
    dtor = [](any_block* s) {
      auto* self = static_cast<any_block_dtor<D>*>(s);
      (*self->dtor_unsafe())( static_cast<T*>(self->ptr) );
    };
  }
};

using any_ptr = std::shared_ptr<any_block>;
template<class T, class...Args>
any_ptr
make_any_ptr(Args&&...args) {
  auto r = std::make_shared<any_block_made<T>>();
  if (!r) return nullptr;
  r->emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return r;
}
template<class T, class D=std::default_delete<T>>
any_ptr wrap_any_ptr( T* t, D&& d = {} ) {
    auto r = std::make_shared<any_block_dtor<std::decay_t<D>>>();
    if (!r) return nullptr;
    r->init( t, std::forward<D>(d) );
    return r;
}
```

you'd have to implement `any_cast`, but with `try_get<T>` it should be easy.

There may be some corner cases like `const T` that the above doesn't handle.

```
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T>
crystalize_any_ptr( any_ptr ptr ) {
  if (!ptr) return nullptr;
  T* pt = ptr->try_get<T>();
  if (!pt) return nullptr;
  return {pt, ptr}; // aliasing constructor
}
```

This lets you take a `any_ptr` and turn it into a `shared_ptr<T>` if the types match without copying anything.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e62ba28be7cd846a).

You'll notice how similar `any_block_made` and `any_block_dtor` is.  I believe that this is why at least one major shared_ptr in a std library reuses the spot the deleter lives in for make_shared itself.

I could probably do similar, and reduce binary size here.  In addition, the `T`/`D` parameter of `any_block_made` and `any_block_dtor` is really just about how big and aligned the block of memory we play with is, and what exactly type erasued helper I store in the `dtor` pointer in the parent.  A compiler/linker with COMDAT folding (MSVC or GOLD) may eliminate the binary bloat here, but with a bit of care I could do it myself.

Comment: Nice, I was surprised such pointer does still not exist in Boost. It would be even better if it could also take ownership over a raw pointer, but I'm pretty happy with it anyway.

Comment: @Anton3 That would just involve adding a destroyer-invoker and a `void*` to `any_block_base`, moving `get_unsafe` to `any_block_base`, having a destroyer-only derived type of `any_block_base`.  Then populate the base destroyer and void ptr in the implementation cases.  Slightly more overhead.

Comment: @Anton3 augmented & live example posted.

Comment: Even a deleter :) Thanks again!

Comment: Found a bug in `any_block_dtor`: deleter is only constructed, but never destructed. Instead of `dtor_data`, plain `D dtor;` should probably be stored.

Comment: @anton fixed.  I am trying to be careful with exceptions at inopportune times, but maybe just storing `D` works.  Note that I had to cleanup in child, as dtor function pointer requires dtor data be constructed!